# MongoDB cluster on a single machine - RHEL8

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-replica-set, rhel8

I followed the following [guide](https://medium.com/swlh/mongodb-creating-a-3-node-replica-set-cluster-7ca94849b139) to create a MongoDB replica-set on a single RHEL 8 VM. I used following commands as mentioned in that guide.

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/var/mongodb/pki/
sudo su
openssl rand -base64 741 > /usr/local/var/mongodb/pki/replicaset-keyfile
chmod 400 /usr/local/var/mongodb/pki/replicaset-keyfile
```

Then, I created a `node1.conf` as described below.

```
storage:
  dbPath: /usr/local/var/mongodb/node1
net:
  bindIp: localhost
  port: 27011
security:
  authorization: enabled
  keyFile: /usr/local/var/mongodb/pki/replicaset-keyfile
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/node1/mongod.log
  logAppend: true
processManagement:
  fork: true
replication:
  replSetName: replicaset-example
```

After that I used following commands as instructed in the guide.

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/var/mongodb/node1
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/node1
```

I did exactly the same thing for `node2` and `node3` as well.

Next step in that guide was `sudo mongod -f node1.conf` which didn't work because `mongod` hadn't been installed on the system. Therefore, I installed `mongod` using `yum`.

After this, the above command worked and I was able to configure a MongoDB replica-set on those three nodes.
However, after restarting the machine port `27011` was no longer active and I couldn't access the replica-set. Default port `27017` (which is mentioned in the config file created on mongodb yum installation) is active and I'm able to use MongoDB on that.

`sudo mongod -f node1.conf` (node2 and node3 as well), allows me to enter to the replica-set again. However, this has to be repeated after each shutdown.

How can I run the replica-set as a normal mongod service(s)?. A guide which would point me in the correct direction is also appreciated.

**Update

I tried adding a new service as guided in the below answer. However, I get this error.

```
Apr 12  localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mongod_node2.service: Control process exited, code=dumped status=6
Apr 12 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mongod_node2.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
```

I changed `Environment` and `PIDFile` variables as instructed. Also, changed the ownership of the keyfile. I tried with and without adding `ExecStartPre` parts. Still the result is the same. I believe there couldn't be an issue with `node1.conf` file as it works fine with `sudo mongod -f node1.conf` command.

Comment: Did you specify the full path of the config files?

Comment: See https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set-with-keyfile-access-control/#std-label-deploy-repl-set-with-auth

Comment: I gave the full path; e.g.: Environment="OPTIONS=-f /home/user123/node2.conf"

Comment: I think the issue is with permissions. 'mongod -f node1.conf' doesn't work without sudo. Could this be the reason?

Comment: Yes, usually files in `/home/user123` are accessible only by user `user123` or by `root` but not by user `mongod`. Typically such config files are stored in `/etc` folder

Comment: I fixed permission issues. Also, I needed to add 'pidFilePath' to node1.conf as well. Thereafter, everything worked nicely! Thanks for your guidance and quick responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First something general: You run all mongod processes on a single machine. In this case you need to set also the `processManagement.pidFilePath`, e.g.

```
processManagement:
  pidFilePath: /var/run/node1/mongod.pid
```

otherwise all processes will use the same default file `/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid` and you have a conflict.

Now, regarding your actual question:

Install it as a service. The easiest way is to check the existing service like this:

```
$ systemctl status mongod
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
```

Make a copy of `/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service` to `/etc/systemd/system/mongod_node1.service`

Edit the copied file and change it according to your preferences. Mainly you need to change lines

```
Environment="OPTIONS=-f /etc/mongod.conf"
PIDFile=/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
```

to

```
Environment="OPTIONS=-f .../node1.conf"
PIDFile=/var/run/node1/mongod.pid
```

adding these lines would be also useful:

```
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /usr/local/var/mongodb/node1
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /usr/local/var/mongodb/node1
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /usr/local/var/mongodb/node1
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/node1
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/node1
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/node1
```

Then you can enable the service with

```
systemctl enable mongod_node1
```

For manual start (if required) use `systemctl start mongod_node1`

Just some notes:

Do not edit service file `/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service` directly. If you run an update of your MongoDB package, then the installer will revert the file to default.

MongoDB is running under user `mongod`, thus you must also change the ownership of the keyfile:

```
 chown mongod:mongod /usr/local/var/mongodb/pki/replicaset-keyfile
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I get an error when I try to start this new service. I have updated the question with that information.